# Java JNI native library loads on 64bit and 32bit, but doesn't run on 32bit

Tags: java, java-native-interface, mingw, 32bit-64bit, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have a JNI application working on my main computer which is Windows 7 64-bit, but it fails to work on my laptop which is Windows XP 32-bit. On the laptop, the 32-bit version of the native DLL loads without an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`, but I get the error when the actual native method is called. Here is how I compile my DLLs using MinGW:

```
cd bin
javah MyClass
move /Y MyClass.h ../
"%mingw64%\bin\g++" -shared -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\include\win32" -o src/lib/MyLibrary.dll MyClass.cpp
@echo "Making the 32-bit library..."
g++ -shared -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\include\win32" -o src/lib/MyLibrary_32.dll MyClass.cpp
```

Here is the code I use to load the library, which technically works on both processors.

```
    String processor = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model").equals("32") ? new String("_32") : new String("");
    try { System.load(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\MyLibrary" + processor + ".dll"); }
    catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        //If the dll was not found, extract the one packaged as a resource in the .jar
        InputStream in = ML_Overworld.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("lib/MyLibrary" + processor + ".dll");
        if(in == null) {
            printError(String.format("MyLibrary%s.dll was not contained in the jar.", processor));
            return;
        }
        File outPath = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\MyLibrary" + processor + ".dll");
        try {
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outPath));
            try {
                int input;
                while((input = in.read()) != -1)
                    out.write(input);
                out.close();
                in.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e2) {
                printError(String.format("MyLibrary%s.dll failed to extract: ", processor) + e2.getMessage() + ".");
                return;
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e3) {
            printError(String.format("MyLibrary%s.dll failed to extract: ", processor) + e3.getMessage() + ".");
            return;
        }
        try { System.load(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\MyLibrary" + processor + ".dll"); }
        catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e4) {
            printError(String.format("MyLibrary%s.dll failed to load: ", processor) + e4.getMessage() + ".");
            return;
        }
    }
```

And for reference, here is the native method which throws an `Unsatisfied Link Error` on the 32-bit laptop:
`public static native void readMap(String path, cMap m);`

---

[solution]: added `--kill-at` to the g++ arguments when compiling the 32-bit DLL.

Comment: Run [depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) against your 32-bit dll.  It sounds like something is missing.  What is g++ vs "%mingw64%\bin\g++"?  Did you try g++ -m32?

Comment: Standard MinGW is 32-bit only. MinGW-64 is a separate application on another website: http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/ . Loading the regular g++ compiled DLL on my 64-bit yields an incompatibility error.

Comment: Fixed, editing the main post with the solution.

Comment: Manual page for [--kill-at](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-g_t_002d_002dkill_002dat-295)