# Why my method throws an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, mingw32, mingw-w64

I have a project with some JNI inside with a makefile to compile a `dll` under Windows 10 64 bit. For a software constraint I need my `dll` library be compiled for 32 bit JRE.

My makefile is the following:

```
CC32=C:\i686-w64-mingw32-gcc\bin\i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe
CC64=C:\Program\ Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-6.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1\mingw64\bin\g++.exe

all: LibJNI32.dll LibJNI64.dll

LibJNI32.dll: LibJNI.cpp LibJNI.h
    ${CC32} -shared -o $@ $< -mtune=generic -m32 -std=gnu++11 -O2 \
    -I. -IC:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\include -IC:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\include\win32

LibJNI64.dll: LibJNI.cpp LibJNI.h
    ${CC64} -shared -o $@ $< -mtune=generic -fPIC -m64 -std=gnu++11 -O2 \
    -I. -IC:\Program\ Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\include -IC:\Program\ Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\include\win32

LibJNI.h: LibJNI.java
    javah -o LibJNI.h -cp ../java my.package.LibJNI
```

While both `LibJNI32.dll` and `LibJNI64.dll` are well loaded by my java program, only call to jni with the `LibJNI64.dll` works. Those of `LibJNI32.dll` throw an `UnsatifiedLinkError`.

Is there something my makefile is missing to compile well for 32 bit ?

Comment: so what version of java are you using?  a 64 bit version maybe?

Comment: I use a 32 bit jre. But since I posted my question, my problem translated to `Can't find dependent libraries`.

Comment: incase you're still stuck - dependency walker is your friend for this

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

If you play with 32/64 bit libs it might be a struggle when you share common system libraries:

- make sure to put 32 bit libs on PATH (ones that your DLL depends on)
- make a simple wrapper code and double check your DLL works outside JVM

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally managed to find the solution here: 
[Java JNI native library loads on 64bit and 32bit, but doesn't run on 32bit [SOLVED]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398646/java-jni-native-library-loads-on-64bit-and-32bit-but-doesnt-run-on-32bit-solv)

The solution is to use the `-Wl,--kill-at` compiler flag for the 32bits dll target.